# Remove characters in inputfield in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I have an inputfield in one scene,there I need a formate like MM/YY,when user enters first two integers `/` should be added immediate to the second character.So I have added following code the inputfield onvalueChanged event

```
 if (ExpiryDateInputField.text.Length == 2)
        {
            ExpiryDateInputField.text = ExpiryDateInputField.text + "/";

            ExpiryDateInputField.MoveTextEnd(false);
        }
```

Here the problem is,when I am trying to remove text the text after `/` is removing but the text before `/`is not removing,Where I am doing wrong.

Ex: If I enter 1234 the input field will display is as 12/34,when I am trying to remove the entered text 3 and 4 are removing while clicking on backspace on keyboard but `12/` are not removing. Is there any way to work it out?

Comment: Can you try by replacing ".text" with ".value"?

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー,Thanks for suggestion.But I have take that field as public InputField ExpiryDateInputField; so it is not showing .value.

Comment: Let's imagine `12/` was there. If you remove the `/` then length will be 2 again. So it adds it back in again (because that is what your code does). It _looks_ like it isn't removing it - but in fact it is removing it, then putting it straight back. You can verify this by deleting the `1` instead - I bet the result will be `2//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is basically this.

You enter "12", OnValueChange is called and "/" is added, now you have "12/".

You press backspace to remove the "/", OnValueChange is called and "/" is added, now you have "12/".

You could try remembering the last value of the `InputField`, and if that value contained a "/", dont append another "/".

```
string last = string.Empty;

public void OnValueChange()
{
    if (ExpiryDateInputField.text.Length == 2 && !last.Contains("/"))
    {
         ExpiryDateInputField.text = ExpiryDateInputField.text + "/";

        ExpiryDateInputField.MoveTextEnd(false);
    }
    last = ExpiryDateInputField.text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much@Fredrik Widerberg,It helped me lot :-)